Date Sorting with Prime React
I'm having issues sorting a datatable with prime react on the Date column.
Here is my code
<Column
    field="Date"
    header="Date"
    sortable={true}
    body={(rowData: any) => formatDate(rowData.Date)}
/>

And this is the function that creates a new date instance:
export const formatDate = (date: any) => {
    if (!date) return '';
    return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        day: '2-digit',
        month: '2-digit',
        year: 'numeric',
    });
};

When I click the Sorting button it just orders it by the first numbers (days). years are month are being sorted

How can this be fixed?

I believe that is happening because you are storing those dates as strings and not as a Date object or a number.

I fixed this mapping the date initially before the conversion
    const formatReport = report.map(item => {
  return {
    ...item,
    Date: new Date(item.Date)
  }
})

This method is called from my DataTable property, report is the useState with data comming from the DB.
  <DataTable
    value={formatReport}//This calls the function to map and make the date(data object)
    style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
    sortField='Date'
    sortOrder={1}
    editMode='cell'
    scrollable
    scrollHeight='45vh'

